# Z3: Is it possible to sum up a BitVec and a Real?

Tags: z3

I'm using Z3py to try to make some experiments on round-off error problem, it turns out that i have to sum up the a BitVec and a Real. However, when I try to do so, i get a 'sort mismatch' error. This is my code:

```
x = BitVecVal(8, 6)
y = Real('y')

solve(y + x == 5)
```

Is there a way to sum a BitVec and a Real? or just to get the Int value of BitVec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Z3 C based API does contain conversion functions from bit-vectors to numerals (integers) and integers can be coerced to reals. 
However, the python API does not expose the relevant function directly, but you can wrap it:

```
x = BitVecVal(2,8)
y = Real('y')


def to_int(x):
    return ArithRef(Z3_mk_bv2int(x.ctx_ref(), x.as_ast(), 0), x.ctx)

print solve(to_int(x) + y == 5)
```

Comment: Great answer, thank u man. I didn't see this in the documentation. However, does this wrap function affect Solver's performance?

Comment: In your example, `x` is a value. So there is no performance impact. The Z3 preprocessor will convert `to_int(x)` into the real number `2`. However, if `x` is not a value, then there is a serious performance impact. The `to_int` will be "blasted" into a big `if-then-else` term that "builds" an integer based on the bits of `x`. We get an `if-then-else` term for each bit. There are "smarter" ways to handle `to_int`, but Z3 currently uses this simple/naive approach.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the bit vector value into a signed long:

```py
x = BitVecVal(8, 6)
y = Real('y')

solve(y + x.as_signed_long() == 5)
# [y = -3]
```

By the way, I found `as_signed_long` by inspecting `y` as one usually does in Python, namely, by `print dir(y)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i really appreciate this. By the way, as_signed_long method is available for BitVecVal only, not for BitVec. What if I want x to be a BitVec instead of a constant? Is there any way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to do with `BitVec` either.