# z3py error when converting int to bitvec

Tags: z3, z3py

From ([Z3: Is it possible to sum up a BitVec and a Real?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476658/z3-is-it-possible-to-sum-up-a-bitvec-and-a-real)) , I tried to convert an int to bitvec using

```
x = Int('x')
reg = BitVecRef(Z3_mk_int2bv(BitVecVal(x.ctx_ref(), 16, x)), x.ctx)
```

but I always get an error saying " 'Ast' object has no attribute 'ref' ", it seems this function can only convert integer to bitvec, is there any other way to convert Int to bitvec?

Also I know this function is treated as uninterpreted for now, do I need to recompile my local version from ([bv-enable-int2bv-propagation option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798984/bv-enable-int2bv-propagation-option)) ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you suggest first tries to convert `x` to a bit-vector value (BitVecVal), i.e., an actual number, but `x` is not a value (number). The right expression can be constructed as follows:

```
x = Int('x')
raw = Z3_mk_int2bv(x.ctx_ref(), 16, x.as_ast())
reg = BitVecRef(raw, x.ctx)
print reg
```

The `int2bv-propagation` fix was added long before the last Z3 release, so if the version you use is less than about a year old you shouldn't have to recompile anything.